# Clicking the Edit related item buttons opens the wrong language version in sitecore 8

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

When Clicking the Edit related item buttons opens the wrong language version
e.g. If I click the Edit related item button in german version, English version if sitecore is opening

When using custom Edit Frame buttons to edit some item fields in Experience Editor, you may encounter a problem that the changes are saved to the wrong language version of the item.
For example, when using the Field Editor button the changes made to the fields in the Field Editor popup might be saved to the item version of UI language instead of content language selected in Experience Editor ribbon.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug. 
You can find here details: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/814090